# How to get the ids of the checkboxes which are displayed on the page dynamically

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, checkbox

I have a jsp page in which there is a html table. The contents of the table will be **populated dynamically** after reading an xml file. Depending on some data present in the xml file, the number of rows in the table may vary from 2 to 10. Now, there is a **checkbox** in each row that is displayed in the html table. **The id of the checkbox is also dynamically named**. Now, I have to write some javascript code which is dependent on all the ids of the the checkboxes that are displayed. How to pass all the ids of the checkboxes that are displayed on the table to the javascript code **dynamically**?

**PS**: Im thinking of this approach, please correct me if im wrong. **Declare an empty array to hold ids of the checkboxes. As I create each row of the table dynamically using a for-loop, I add the ids of the checkboxes to the array. Now, Im thinking to use this array in the javascript.**

Is it possible to access this array in the javascript? If so, How do I pass on this array to the javascript block?  Are there any restrictions on where to place this javascript code in the jsp(like after/before the code block where the ids of the checkboxes get added to the array). Im relatively new to this kind of stuff. Pls help on implementing this approach

Comment: Use jQuery. Then, say you have those checkboxes inside a container with id 'container'; now you just need to do: $('#container input[type=checkbox]')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood you have two possibilities. You could

1. add the id of the checkbox to a javascript array for every iteration on the server-side `for` loop. So you need to declare an empty js array at the begin of your page , then you add a `script` block for each checkbox, in which you push the id into the array with `<yourarray>.push("<yourid>")`. This solution is not really performant (since each `<script>` block stops the rendering process for a while and you "sow" the code in several places) but technically is working - otherwise
2. at `DOM ready` (or onload) event you look at the `input:checkbox` DOM collection, get the id and push it into the array, like so.

   ```
   var ids = [],
       cbx = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

   for (i = 0, l = cbx.length; i < l; i++) {
          ids.push(cbx[i].id);
   }

   console.log(ids);
   ```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G44hH/1/ - Of course if you can, it's better if use this solution (and not the first one)

Comment: Interesting [queryselector](http://caniuse.com/queryselector) and [console](http://patik.com/blog/complete-cross-browser-console-log/) - I would say mine is safer and not much more code

Comment: yes, I absolutely agree (even if `querySelectorAll()` is supported since IE8). It's just to present a different approach. Console is just placed for debug purposes

Answer (score 2):

Yes similarly with mplungjan's answer you can search for elements types and then dig further down to retrieve checkbox elements within

So in your case search for your table by id (if you have given it an id) or by tagname('table'[0] if it is the first and only table), search for checkbox elements inside the table and add each to your array

```
var table   = document.getElementById('dataTable');
//OR if we assert there's only 1 table
//var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]; 
var tableInputTags = table.getElementsByTagName("input");
var checkboxArray= [];

for (var i=0; i<tableInputTags.length; i++) 
{
    if(tableInputTags[i].type=="checkbox") 
    {
        checkboxArray.push(tableInputTags[i].id);
    }
}
//continue doing something with the 
//array of dynamically created checkboxes...
```

Comment: this approach also is not working for IE7 and below. But this seems to be straightforward approach. A small typo is there in the if condition(we shud use tableInputTags[i] instead of inputs[i])

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the checkboxes are available after page load, you can do this (plain javascript):

```
var checks=[];
window.onload=function() {
  var inputs = document.getElemementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0, n=inputs.name;i<n;i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type=="checkbox") checks.push(inputs[i].id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table with id #table have some TRs inside TRs you have check box in TD. you can do it by jquery below:

```
$('#table tr').each(function() {
 alert($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('id'));
});
```

But I guess you not need to store all check box id you need to id of check box with related to a particular Td in which you are doing something like delete edit etc.

I can send you proper code if you can specify clearly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

add a class attribute for all the checckboxes and then use jquery to select these checkboxes by class.

The jquery selector will return an array of these check-boxes, then you can use this array according to your need.
Something like this.

```
<input type=checkbox class ="box"/>

var arr = [];

arr = $(".box");
```